# Implementing Scheme's if clause using only cond

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

Question:
Consider a metacircular evaluator which does not implement the if construct, but only a cond. Louis Reasoner
claims that if is unnecessary, since we could evaluate the following procedure using the metacircular evaluator:

```
(define (if predicate action alternative)
  (cond (predicate action)
        (else alternative)))
```

Explain why this does not work. In particular, suppose you use this if procedure to define factorial:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

The result of evaluating (factorial 3) using the if statement above makes the program running forever, but I have no idea why. Any hint on this will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I printed the n in the factorial loops, and n is decreasing from 3 to negative infinity. Even though n already equals to 0 after a couple loops, the program is still not stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` expression is a *special form*, it doesn't follow the same evaluation rules as a normal procedure - hence it can't be implemented by a procedure, it has to use a syntactical transformation (say, using a macro or in your case, changing the underlying interpreter). To see this, look at this simple example:

```
(if #t 'ok (/ 1 0))
=> 'ok
```

The division by zero never occurred, because only the `'ok` part of the expression got evaluated. Try to evaluate the same expression using your implementation of `if` - you'll get a `division by zero` error.

So now you see, an `if` expression is evaluated differently depending on the value of the condition, only the consequent is executed *or* only the alternative is executed, but never both. And that's the reason why your `factorial` example fails - even if the base case is reached, the other branch is also executed, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `if/cond` are syntax, not procedures. There is a difference in using the [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=if#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._if%29%29) *syntax*, and actually defining it and trying to use it. To illustrate, consider the following:

```
(+ 1 (- 4 2))
```

Here we have the [`+`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=%2B#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._%2B%29%29) procedure, that takes zero or more **numbers** and returns their sum. We have applied the procedure with two arguments, the second being an expression `(- 4 2)` instead of a *value*. Notice that this will not result in a contract violation error, and actually evaluate to 3. Why? Because **any argument which is not a value is first simplified to a value**. So the expression evaluates as:

```
(+ 1 (- 4 2))
=> (+ 1 2)
=> 3
```

Coming back to your *defined* `if` procedure, the same rules apply, in that any arguments passed to the function, that are not values themselves, will be reduced to values before using the `if` procedure. So the evaluation for `(factorial 1)` becomes:

```
(factorial 1)
=> (if (= 1 1) 1 (* 1 (factorial 0)))
=> (if #t 1 (* 1 (factorial 0)))
=> (if #t 1 (* 1 (if (= 0 1) 1 (* 0 (factorial -1)))))
=> (if #t 1 (* 1 (if #f 1 (* 0 (factorial -1)))))
=> ... (endless loop to negative infinity)
```

This is different from using the `if` *syntax*, where evaluation is short circuited, meaning that the `else` case is only evaluated *if* the predicate is false. For example,

```
(if #t 1 (+ 1 'a))
```

will **not** throw an error for trying to add a number and a symbol, because it will not evaluate the else-expression in the first place (since predicate evaluates to true). Hence, it returns 1.